# swi-prolog [lists]

Tags: prolog

Hey i was working on this little method i guess you call them messing around trying to get my grip on swi-prolog before I have my big project assigned in a week or so at university. Its pretty obvious what it does say i say "colors(yellow,F). it will give me banana, lemon and so on...

```
colors(C,F):-fruits(F,C)
```

Now my question is i know i can use list_to_set(F, (something else)), to make the output into one list instead of having to hit ';' to get all of the fruits. THOUGH... is there anyway i can incorporate the list making into the actual method?

cheers!

Comment: Yea. Thats what i meant. List_to_set just gets rid of duplicates. So i was saying is there a way to say findall(C,colors(yellow,F),Fruits). but instead of using the findall out here when you are actually queuering the database, can you include it inside the method itself so you can just say colors(C,F). without the findall and still get a list?

Comment: okay! well then can i incorporate that into the actual method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay found out how to:

```
colors(C,F):-findall(C,fruits(F,C),C).
```

simple enough, just had to stick it in there. Thanks Anyways!